# dynamically change visibility of markers

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular 1.2.15 and angular-google-maps 1.0.18 to display several dozen markers.  What I want to do is independently turn on/off the visibility of groups of markers (as designated by class name) dynamically.  I'm able to use the angular-google-maps directive to render the map and all of the markers.  I just don't know how to dynamically change marker visibility with angular-google-maps.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">
  <markers ng-repeat="blotter in blotters" class="{{blotter.name}}" models="blotter.stories" options="{visible:true}" coords="'self'" doCluster="true">
  </markers>
</google-map>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.map = {
  center: {latitude: 39.111, longitude: -119.89},
  zoom: 10
};

$scope.blotters= [{ 'stories': [], 'title': 'Local News', 'name': 'local_news', 'id': 1, 'filterString': filterString1},
        { 'stories': [], 'title': 'Sports', 'name': 'sports', 'id': 2,  'filterString': filterString2},
        { 'stories': [], 'title': 'Local Government','name': 'local_government', 'id': 3, 'filterString': filterString3}];
```

And in another function (not shown here) I load each blotter's stories.  Each of those stories has a latitude and longitude attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this by switching from angular-google-maps to [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps).  Then, I implemented markers using the standard Google maps api to add a marker object to each story in the scope.  See [here](https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/dynamic_markers.html) for an example.